# How to find an optimal sample size (or range) based on sampling errors?

Tags: optimization, sample-size, small-sample

### Intro to problem

Increasing the sample size can be very costly in terms of time and money. However, in experiments where we measure proportions within a sample, errors associated with the sample size can be notoriously high. This is especially true when we measure proportions as low as 1%. I computed the margin of error (MOE) with a 95% confidence interval (zi) for the proportions 1%, 5% and 10%, over an array of sample sizes (n) as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 MOE = z_i\sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Below**, the MOE is shown as absolut error, from which the relative error is calculated. For example, if a proportion of 10% has an MOE=5, it can be expressed as 10+-5%, which corresponds to 50% of relative error (5/10*100).

[image]

### Questions

Is there any analytical method/approach to find an optimal sample size (or range), whilst keeping errors at an `acceptable` range? Or, this is subject to each specific study, where `acceptable` will have completely different meanings?

Even if this problem is highly dependent on the limitations and targets for each study, are there any good practices or general rules?

Comment: Can explain what you mean by relative and absolute error in the graph above? For binomial data, variance is greatest at 0.5 so you can calculate standard errors for a proportion of 0.5 and proportions greater or less than 0.5 will have smaller standard errors.

Comment: Absolut error in the graph is the margin of error (MOE). For instance, a proportion of 10% with a MOE=5 will be 10+-5%, which corresponds to 50% of relative error (5/10*100). The margin of error is calculated as the product of the z*-value and the root square of the squared standard deviation divided by the sample size (as [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/margin-of-error/#:~:text=The%20margin%20of%20error%20can,Standard%20error%20of%20the%20sample.)).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There's no optimal answer here. If you need a margin of error that doesn't exceed x, then you can determine what sample size you need. Typically, you can determine this based on what you want to do with the data after you've collected it. In other cases, you'll only have funding/time for a sample size of y.